# fire events from widget inside repetition widget

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I'm experimenting with the repetition widget to make things easier to create reports. But I ran into the following problem.

When I use a chart widget in the repetition widget with a on Row Click event, it seems not propagating it to the report. If I use the same widget outside the repetition widget the event is fired!

Is this a know issue or do I have to configure additional settings in the repetition widget to make this work?